# Error in CRUD Functions for child tables - Referential integrity constraint violation:

Tags: java, rest, postman

I'm using Rest controllers to populate data in my Postman. I have three tables with two of them having OneToMany relationships.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/vehicle")   
@Slf4j     
public class VehicleRest 

{
 private VehicleService vehicleService;

public VehicleRest(VehicleService vehicleService) {
    this.vehicleService = vehicleService;
}

@GetMapping("/")        // get statement
public Iterable<Vehicle> getAllVehicle() {
    return vehicleService.findAll();
}

@PostMapping("/")       //create new
public ResponseEntity<Vehicle> addVehicle(@RequestBody Vehicle vehicle) {
    return new ResponseEntity<>(
            vehicleService.saveVehicle(vehicle),
            HttpStatus.CREATED
    );
}

@PutMapping("/")        //update statement
public ResponseEntity<Vehicle> updateVehicle(@RequestBody Vehicle vehicle) {
    return new ResponseEntity<>(
            vehicleService.saveVehicle(vehicle),
            HttpStatus.ACCEPTED
    );
}

@PatchMapping("/{id}") // passes in the variable as an id, partial update
public ResponseEntity<?> partialUpdateDynamic(
        @RequestBody Map<String, Object> updates,
        @PathVariable Integer id) {
    return new ResponseEntity<>(
            vehicleService.patchVehicle(updates, id),
            HttpStatus.ACCEPTED
    );
}

@DeleteMapping("/{id}")     //cut out, didnt like her anyways
public void deleteVehicleById(@PathVariable Integer id){
    vehicleService.deleteVehicleById(id);
}

@GetMapping()               // find by specific paramaters
public ResponseEntity<Vehicle> findlicensePlateOrId(@RequestParam(required = false) Integer id,
                                                    @RequestParam(required = false) String licensePlate) {
    if (licensePlate != null && !licensePlate.isEmpty()) {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(vehicleService.findBylicensePlateOrId(null, id));
    }
    return null;
}

@GetMapping("{id}")             // find by id only
public ResponseEntity<Vehicle> findByIdInPath(@PathVariable Integer id) {
    return ResponseEntity.ok(vehicleService.findBylicensePlateOrId(null, id));
}

@GetMapping("/test")            // test to make sure we be connected and shid
public ResponseEntity <String> welcomeDevs() {      // carrots hold what will be in ok
    return ResponseEntity.ok("Welcome back devs");
}
```

}

I have a SeedData class for creating the initial data in the tables.

```
@Component
public class SeedData implements CommandLineRunner {
    public SeedData(VehicleService vehicleService, VehicleMakeService vehicleMakeService, VehicleModelService vehicleModelSerivce) {
        this.vehicleService = vehicleService;
        this.vehicleMakeService = vehicleMakeService;
        this.vehicleModelService = vehicleModelSerivce;
}

private final VehicleModelService vehicleModelService;
private final VehicleService vehicleService;
private final VehicleMakeService vehicleMakeService;


@Override
public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
    // Setting Vehicle fields
    Vehicle vehicle1 = new Vehicle();
    vehicle1.setYear(2013);
    vehicle1.setLicensePlate("Z15304");
    vehicle1.setVin("0ALJ48FKJH12394");
    vehicle1.setColor("Black");
    vehicleService.saveVehicle(vehicle1);

    Vehicle vehicle2 = new Vehicle();
    vehicle2.setYear(2014);
    vehicle2.setLicensePlate("L09A12");
    vehicle2.setVin("HD18SJNSODPF891");
    vehicle2.setColor("Blue");
    vehicleService.saveVehicle(vehicle2);

    Vehicle vehicle3 = new Vehicle();
    vehicle3.setYear(2015);
    vehicle3.setLicensePlate("A9UJF4");
    vehicle3.setVin("KS843L0987DK147");
    vehicle3.setColor("Purple");
    vehicleService.saveVehicle(vehicle3);

    VehicleMake vehicleMake1 = new VehicleMake();
    vehicleMake1.setYear(2013);
    vehicleMake1.setVehicleMakeName("Ford");
    vehicleMakeService.saveVehicleMake(vehicleMake1);

    VehicleMake vehicleMake2 = new VehicleMake();
    vehicleMake2.setYear(2014);
    vehicleMake2.setVehicleMakeName("Chevrolet");
    vehicleMakeService.saveVehicleMake(vehicleMake2);

    VehicleMake vehicleMake3 = new VehicleMake();
    vehicleMake3.setYear(2016);
    vehicleMake3.setVehicleMakeName("Mitsubishi");
    vehicleMakeService.saveVehicleMake(vehicleMake3);

    VehicleModel vehicleModel1 = new VehicleModel();
    vehicleModel1.setVehicleModelName("Raptor");
    vehicleModelService.saveVehicleModel(vehicleModel1);

    VehicleModel vehicleModel2 = new VehicleModel();
    vehicleModel2.setVehicleModelName("Impala");
    vehicleModelService.saveVehicleModel(vehicleModel2);

    VehicleModel vehicleModel3 = new VehicleModel();
    vehicleModel3.setVehicleModelName("Lancer");
    vehicleModelService.saveVehicleModel(vehicleModel3);

    List<Vehicle> vList1 = new ArrayList<>();
    vList1.add(vehicle1);

    List<Vehicle> vList2 = new ArrayList<>();
    vList2.add(vehicle2);

    List<Vehicle> vList3 = new ArrayList<>();
    vList3.add(vehicle3);

    vehicleModel1.setVehicle(vList1);
    vehicleModel2.setVehicle(vList2);
    vehicleModel3.setVehicle(vList3);

    vehicleModelService.saveVehicleModel(vehicleModel1);
    vehicleModelService.saveVehicleModel(vehicleModel2);
    vehicleModelService.saveVehicleModel(vehicleModel3);

    List<VehicleModel> vmList1 = new ArrayList<>();
    vmList1.add(vehicleModel1);

    List<VehicleModel> vmList2 = new ArrayList<>();
    vmList2.add(vehicleModel2);

    List<VehicleModel> vmList3 = new ArrayList<>();
    vmList3.add(vehicleModel3);

    vehicleMake1.setVehicleModel(vmList1);
    vehicleMake2.setVehicleModel(vmList2);
    vehicleMake3.setVehicleModel(vmList3);

    vehicleMakeService.saveVehicleMake(vehicleMake1);
    vehicleMakeService.saveVehicleMake(vehicleMake2);
    vehicleMakeService.saveVehicleMake(vehicleMake3);
}
```

}

Here is a class with a relationship.

```
@Entity
@Data
public class VehicleMake {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)

    private Integer id;

    @Column(unique = true)
    private String vehicleMakeName;
    private Integer year;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<VehicleModel> vehicleModel;

}
```

The issue that I am having is in the Crud functions. In the parent table I am able to manipulate the data without an issue. I am unable to update or delete anything in the child tables without getting the below exception:

```
2022-09-28 12:43:12.801 ERROR 570807 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Referential integrity constraint violation: "FK9STO574BS4V9KE5O2BS5JHIJ5: PUBLIC.VEHICLE_MAKE_VEHICLE_MODEL FOREIGN KEY(VEHICLE_MODEL_ID) REFERENCES PUBLIC.VEHICLE_MODEL(ID) (1)"; SQL statement:
```

This is my service interface and implementation with Overrides:

```
public interface VehicleMakeService {

VehicleMake findById(Integer id);

Iterable<VehicleMake> findAll();

VehicleMake patchVehicleMake(Map<String, Object> updates, Integer id);

VehicleMake saveVehicleMake(VehicleMake vehicleMake);

VehicleMake updateVehicleMake(VehicleMake vehicleMake);

void deleteVehicleMake(Integer id);
```

}

@Service
public class VehicleMakeServiceImpl implements VehicleMakeService {

```
private VehicleMakeRepo vehicleMakeRepo;

public VehicleMakeServiceImpl(VehicleMakeRepo vehicleMakeRepo) {
    this.vehicleMakeRepo = vehicleMakeRepo;
}

public Iterable <VehicleMake> findAll() {
    return vehicleMakeRepo.findAll();
}

@Override
public VehicleMake patchVehicleMake(Map<String, Object> updates, Integer id) throws FieldNotFoundException {
    //find the product by id or throw and exception
    VehicleMake vehicleMakeToPatch = vehicleMakeRepo.findById(id)
            .orElseThrow(() -> new VehicleMakeNotFoundException(String.valueOf(id)));
    // iterate over the map of fields to update
    updates.forEach((k, o) -> {
        System.out.println(k + ":" + o);

        // use reflection to get the setter/accessor for field name
        try {
            Field nameField = vehicleMakeToPatch.getClass().getDeclaredField(k);
            // set the field to the value
            nameField.setAccessible(true);
            nameField.set(vehicleMakeToPatch, o);
            // handle exceptions
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException | IllegalAccessException e) {
            throw new FieldNotFoundException(k);
        }
    });
    return vehicleMakeRepo.save(vehicleMakeToPatch);
}

@Override
public VehicleMake saveVehicleMake(VehicleMake vehicleMake) {
    return vehicleMakeRepo.save(vehicleMake);
}

@Override
public VehicleMake updateVehicleMake(VehicleMake vehicleMake) {
    return vehicleMakeRepo.save(vehicleMake);
}

@Override
public void deleteVehicleMake(Integer id) {
    vehicleMakeRepo.deleteById(id);
}

@Override
public VehicleMake findById(Integer id) {
    return (VehicleMake) vehicleMakeRepo.findById(id)
            .orElseThrow(() -> new VehicleMakeNotFoundException(String.valueOf(id)));
}
```

}

I understand that there is foreign key constraint that is happening, I do not understand the solution to being able to manipulate the child table without having that constraint trigger. I'm probably having some tunnel vision with it at this point.

Comment: We are missing quite a lot of important information here. You only showed us your controller method and only a single sub-entity. You need to show us the service layer as well.

Comment: Updated with service implementation.